# mylatexformat - omit content from format compilation \endofdump?

Tags: format-files

**EDIT 2:**
`\csname endofdump\endcsname` solved my issues

**EDIT:**
I should have added that I get an *Undefined control sequence* error when compiling pdfLaTeX with `\endofdump` WITHOUT a preloaded format, but WITH a preloaded format it works, which lead me to believe that it did not work as I had wished. So I tried a commented out `\endofdump` since according to the `mylatexformat` doc page 3, it looks for lines that contain `\endofdump`. I can achieve the behavior I want exactly by using `\endofdump`, the only caveat is that I need to comment it out if I want to compile the document used for the format. I suspect I need a package for `\endofdump`, but `\usepackage{mylatexformat}` throws a not found error.

---

I can successfully use `mylatexformat` with pdflatex, but am running into some confusion.

I would only like `mylatexformat` to pre-compile the first, lets say half of the preamble--so I would like to exclude content after a certain point. Is this possible?

As far as I can tell, `\endofdump` only works to include content after the format is loaded. But I want to omit content from the format.

To compile the format file, I have a batch script:

`pdflatex -ini -jobname="format" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx """MWEformat.tex"""`

I have a MWE below:

**Stage one: compiling format success**

```latex
%& COMPILE THE FORMAT LIKE THIS format
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\testOne}{Command One works}
%%% I would only like my format to contain the above two lines
%\endofdump  % End of dump only works for when we use format, not compile it 
\newcommand{\testTwo}{Command Two works}  % this is included in format, but I don't want it to be
\begin{document}
    \testOne\\
    \testTwo
\end{document}
```

**Stage two: loading format success**

```latex
%&format
%preamble precompiled, this works
\begin{document}
    \testOne\\
    \testTwo
\end{document}
```

**Stage three: `\endofdump` works when I want to include content after the format**

```latex
%&format
\renewcommand{\testTwo}{Command Two change attempt!!!}  % interestingly, this will work with no space between it and \begin{documet}... but it wont work if there's a line space betwen this and \begin{documet} (as expected).

\endofdump
\renewcommand{\testTwo}{Command Two changed success!!!}  % since end of dump applied, now I can change the command

\begin{document}
    \testOne\\
    \testTwo
\end{document}
```

What I actually want from Stage 3 is an error: I do not want `\testTwo` to be included in the format, so instead of `\renewcommand` I would have to use `\newcommand`.

Comment: `\endofdump` is supposed to do what you want

Comment: I get an *Undefined control sequence* error on it when compiling pdfLaTeX with `\endofdump`... but I see that I can still create the format file without compiling LaTeX and omit values past `\endofdump`. Do you know if there is a way I can use `\endofdump` without a preloaded format? I suspect I need a package for `\endofdump`, but `\usepackage{mylatexformat}` throws a not found error.

Comment: that's why I used a comment marker rather than a command in the original latexformat.ltx code but the authoe of mylatexformat didn't like that and changed it to a command, I assume that you cam put `\providecommand\endofdump{}` before that in the preamble so it is defined to do nothing if it is not already defined

Comment: My impression is that you should use `\csname endofdump\endcsname`

Comment: @egreg I think it needs to be explicit `\long\def\MYLATEX@endofdump ##1\endofdump`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's code by FC, so buggy by definition and with unfathomable documentation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I wasn't sure that you would be notified about the comment by the OP directed towards you, since it didn't include your tag.